# How to read and write Map<String, Object> from/to parquet file in Java or Scala?

Tags: java, scala, avro, parquet

Looking for a concise example on how to read and write `Map<String, Object>` from/to parquet file in Java or Scala?

Here is expected structure, using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`  as serializer in Java (i.e. looking for equivalent using parquet):

```
public static Map<String, Object> read(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {

    });
}

public static void write(OutputStream outputStream, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, map);        
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-pig/src/main/java/parquet/pig/ParquetLoader.java

Comment: [This question does not show any research effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223482/206336)

Comment: @Ajoy question purposefully distilled to the essence, but I'll add a level of detail

Comment: @sid_dude that's a multi-file project for reading Apache Pig file (which all the schema "magic"), need an example for Map<String, Object> without extraneous dependencies (also use answer box below to get credit;)

Answer (score 3):

i'm not quite good about parquet but, from [here](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/test/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/TestReadWrite.java):

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(Resources.getResource("map.avsc").openStream());

    File tmp = File.createTempFile(getClass().getSimpleName(), ".tmp");
    tmp.deleteOnExit();
    tmp.delete();
    Path file = new Path(tmp.getPath());

    AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer = 
        new AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord>(file, schema);

    // Write a record with an empty map.
    ImmutableMap emptyMap = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>().build();
    GenericData.Record record = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema)
        .set("mymap", emptyMap).build();
    writer.write(record);
    writer.close();

    AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = new AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord>(file);
    GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();

    assertNotNull(nextRecord);
    assertEquals(emptyMap, nextRecord.get("mymap"));
```

In your situation change `ImmutableMap` (Google Collections) with a default Map as below:

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse( Resources.getResource( "map.avsc" ).openStream() );

        File tmp = File.createTempFile( getClass().getSimpleName(), ".tmp" );
        tmp.deleteOnExit();
        tmp.delete();
        Path file = new Path( tmp.getPath() );

        AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord>( file, schema );

        // Write a record with an empty map.
        Map<String,Object> emptyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // not empty any more
        emptyMap.put( "SOMETHING", new SOMETHING() );
        GenericData.Record record = new GenericRecordBuilder( schema ).set( "mymap", emptyMap ).build();
        writer.write( record );
        writer.close();

        AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = new AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord>( file );
        GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();

        assertNotNull( nextRecord );
        assertEquals( emptyMap, nextRecord.get( "mymap" ) );
```

I didn't test the code, but give it a try..

Comment: I think that would not work; the key is to serialize `Map<String, Object>` and I am not sure if map.avsc (the AVRO schema?) can support the `Object` part (i.e. must be a concrete type, which defeats the purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a solution to this readily available. When you talk about Maps, its still possible to create a AvroSchema out of it provided the values of the maps is a primitive type, or a complexType which inturn has primitive type fields.

In your case,

- If you have a Map => which will create schema with
  values of map being int.
- If you have a Map,

  - a. CustomObject has fields int, float, char ... (i.e. any primitive type) the schema
    generation will be valid and can then be used to successfully convert
    to parquet.
  - b. CustomObject has fields which are non primitive, the
    schema generated will be malformed and the resulting ParquetWritter
    will fail.

To resolve this issue, you can try to convert your object into a `JsonObject` and then use the Apache Spark libraries to convert it to Parquet.

Answer (score -1):

Apache Drill is your answer!

Convert to parquet : You can use the CTAS(create table as) feature in drill. By default drill creates a folder with parquet files after executing the below query. You can substitute any query and drill writes the output of you query into parquet files

```
create table file_parquet as select * from dfs.`/data/file.json`;
```

Convert from parquet : We also use the CTAS feature here, however we request drill to use a different format for writing the output

```
alter session set `store.format`='json';
create table file_json as select * from dfs.`/data/file.parquet`;
```

Refer to http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/ for more information

Comment: This is not really meeting the spirit of the question - i.e. standalone program.  `Drill` is yet another heavy-ish framework dependency.